# within in the div iframe not displaying in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

In the code below, the left side `div` is displaying correctly, but the right side of the `div` in that `iframe` is displaying outside of the `div`. It is displaying top, but I want to display with in the `div` space.

**html**

```
<div id="details">
        <div id="left">
         <h2>Bangalore</h2>
    <img src="img/vcare_logo.png" width="100" height="83" alt="smoothy html5 template" hspace="50"/>
     <p><b><strong>rgd</b></strong><br>gf560032</p>
    </div>
   <div id="right">
   <h2>Upcoming News</h2>
<iframe id="NewsWindow" seamless src="news_win.htm" width="150" height="204" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; border: #000000 1px solid;"></iframe>   
</div>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
#details  {   
  overflow:auto;
  width: 1050px;
  border: 1px solid black; 
  background: gray;
  margin: 2em auto;
}
#details h2{
  background-color: #A52A2A;
  color: #FFFFFF; 
  font: 13px arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
}
#left, #right {
  width: 45%; 
  margin:5px; 
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
}

#left {   
  float:left;

}
#right {   
  width: 158px; 
  border: #000000 1px solid; 
  background-color: #339999; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 0px 2px 7px 2px; 
  position: absolute; 
  visibility: visible; 
  left: 100px; 
  top: 100px; 
  z-index:3;
  float:right; 
}
```

Comment: Right gets two widths, one 45%, one 158px, you also don't need left of you use float right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all change your html code from `<p><b><strong>rgd</b></strong>��` to `<p><strong><b>rgd</b></strong>`.

and then change your css for `#right`, remove absolute positioning and make it float left as:

```
#right {
    width: 158px;
    border: #000000 1px solid;
    background-color: #339999;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px 2px 7px 2px;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    z-index:3;
    float:left;
}
```